# Trying to select property from array within object, within array. Thrown TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to make a project with React that can display course homework on a to-do list. I currently have some test data, shown here:

```
 const courses = [
    {
      courseName: "Fundies 2",
      classCode: "CS2510",
      startTime: "4:35 PM",
      location: "236 Richards Hall",
      color: "red",
      homework: [{ hwName: "HW3", timeDue: "8:30 PM" }]
    },
    {
      courseName: "Mathematical Reasoning",
      classCode: "MATH1365",
      startTime: "10:20 AM",
      location: "235 Ryder Hall",
      color: "blue",
      homework: [
        { hwName: "HW2", timeDue: "midnight" },
        { hwName: "HW3", timeDue: "midnight" },
      ]
    },
  ];
```

I made a function to create a component out of this data, shown below.

```
const formattedCourses = courses.map((course) => {
    return (
      <Task
        key={course.homework[1].hwName}
        timeDue={course.homework[1].timeDue}
        courseName={course.courseName}
        hwName={course.homework[1].hwName}
        color={course.color}
      />
    );
  });
```

I want the component to be made with the first entry in the homework array. However, whenever I try to compile, I get

> "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'hwName')"

How can I fix this?

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You index is incorrect. If you want the first entry then it should be 0 instead of 1

```
const formattedCourses = courses.map((course) => {
    return (
      <Task
        key={course.homework[0].hwName}
        timeDue={course.homework[0].timeDue}
        courseName={course.courseName}
        hwName={course.homework[0].hwName}
        color={course.color}
      />
    );
  });
```

Comment: Wow. I knew it was going to be something this simple and stupid. hahahah, thank you @Mohit Mutha